# Is it possible to typeset text inside math without amsmath?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, text-mode

Is it possible to typeset text properly inside math without `amsmath`?

Typically I typeset short text using `mathrm`, or `text` (amsmath) within equation:

```
$M_\mathrm{effective mass}$
$M_\text{effective mass}$
```

`\mathrm` works most of the time but is not a real text environment (for example the spaces are ignored as in math mode). On the other hand `\text` depends on `amsmath`.

The question is, is possible to create the same result as with `text` but without using `amsmath`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To have a functionality similar to `amsmath`'s `\text`, but without loading any of the AMS-family packages, you can simply copy into your preamble a modification of the code for `\text` from `amstext.sty`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\text}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text@\else\expandafter\mbox\fi}
\let\nfss@text\text
\def\text@#1{{\mathchoice
  {\textdef@\displaystyle\f@size{#1}}%
  {\textdef@\textstyle\f@size{#1}}%
  {\textdef@\textstyle\sf@size{#1}}%
  {\textdef@\textstyle \ssf@size{#1}}%
  \check@mathfonts
  }%
}
\def\textdef@#1#2#3{\hbox{{%
                    \everymath{#1}%
                    \let\f@size#2\selectfont
                    #3}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$\text{effective mass}$

$M_\text{effective mass}$

$A_{M_\text{effective mass}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While this probably works, there much more in `amstext` than what appears here; the purpose of `\iffirstchoice@`, for instance, is avoiding that something important is executed four times.

Comment: @egreg: Do mean that this solution is inefficient? What is executed four times?

Comment: @alfC This is as efficient as `\text`; what I wanted to say is that `\text` takes even some other precaution. In both cases the argument of `\text` is typeset four times, and this is unavoidable, if you want that the text changes sizes in subscripts or superscripts.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

Defining a macro `\mtext` (which can be used like `\text` from amsmath) as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mtext}[1]{%
{\mbox{\tiny #1}}%
}%

\begin{document}
$M_\mtext{effective mass}$ is the effective mass.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**First try**
Use `\mbox{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$M_{\mbox{effective mass}}$
\end{document}
```

**Note** While using as subscript or superscipt, put `\mbox{}` inside braces like `_{\mbox{...}}`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. two details: 1) it is unfortunate that one needs the extra braces, 2) when using in sub/superscript the resulting text is not smaller but the same as normal text.

Comment: @alfC: 1. Can't help with extra braces. No alternatives. 2. It is because the content inside is in text mode. You can reduce the size by issuing  `\footnotesize` manually. You can write a macro to automate things.

Comment: ok, so I guess this is the reason that `\text` in amsmath exists, so it can take care of all this automatically.

Comment: @alfC: See the edit in my answer.